# How to Host swaggerUI in Azure functions app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, swagger-ui, openapi

I am working in micro service architecture application hosted in Azure functions app and we have swagger UI working locally in one of the repository but have questions about below.

1. How can I host swaggerUI in azure ? Should I use azure functions app?
2. How to combine multiple repository swaggerUI into one combined swaggerUI and host it in azure?

Really appreciate any response I can get

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same case yesterday and I managed to host a Swagger UI on Azure Functions with the [swagger-ui-dist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-dist) package.

I then followed [this tutorial](https://scale-tone.github.io/2019/09/02/how-to-serve-static-content-with-azure-functions) to make the routes work.

In practice, you basically get the static files for Swagger UI, and then make a "webserver-like" logic to serve them.

Hope this helps!